# After updating ui-bootstrap version, datepicker validation got break

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I updated the `ui-bootstrap` version from `0.13.0` to `0.13.4`, It broke the validation on `datepicker` field.

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MC6erINJOlr3mK4AsVDm?p=preview)** with a problem

Previously I was using 0.13.0 and it was working fine.

Basically when I tried to populate `datepicker` value from database, which returned by server as `2015-10-15T04:00:00`, it gets bound correct to datepicker, but additionally it is adding `ng-invalid-date` to `datepicker-popup` element. Because of this `ng-invalid` on input field `datepicker` element shown with `red` border.

Further digging into it, I found that there were some changes made while **[releasing 0.13.2](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-0132-2015-08-02)** related to `dateParser` which removes the creation of `new Date` when its invalid.

Github [**Issue link**](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4559)

Any workaround would appreciate.

Comment: So, what's the question? It's appears to be a bug, but not a valid SO question, no?

Comment: Yes..but i need good work arond to fix it..as it went on prod..also the ui-bootstrap team doesn't provide a solution on it..

Answer (score 0):

The red outline can be suppressed by using Date.parse() on your incoming datetime.

```
$scope.dt = Date.parse('2015-10-15T04:00:00');
```

If you need to support IE < 9, there are polyfills available for Date.parse() which is not correctly supported.